# How to convert JSON Array in JSON Object

Tags: json

I have a JSON Array in below format which I want to convert to JSON Object in (key,value) pair.
Since I am new to JSON I don't know how to achieve this.

```
{
    "id": [
        "100",
        "101",
        "102"
    ],
    "Name": [
        "ajit",
        "amol",
        "kiran"
    ],
    "sex": [
        "Male",
        "Male",
        "Male"
    ]
}
```

I want to convert above in the format like

```
[
    {
        "id": "100",
        "Name": "ajit",
        "Sex": "Male"
    },
    {
        "id": "101",
        "Name": "amol",
        "Sex": "Male"
    },
    {
        "id": "102",
        "Name": "kiran",
        "Sex": "Male"
    }
]
```

Can you guys share your valuable thoughts on how to do this please?

Ajit

Comment: what programming language you used ?

Comment: Why is it generated in that weird form?

Comment: what made you to generate this format? why dont you create in json format only?

Comment: Actually i have a requirement where i want to store duplicate values in Java HashMap. To achive this have created my own Class which extends HashMap and stores the duplicate values. I am coverting this HashMap to JSON String using Google's Gson which is returning the String in this format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming lots of things this works for the example, 
          var arrayOfObjects = [] ;

```
/**
 * @params Object obj formated like the first one
 */
var i = 0,
    arrayOfObjects = [] ;

for( prop in obj ) {
    if ( prop instanceof Array ) {
         for( i = 0 ; i < obj[prop].length ; ++i ) {
              if ( typeof arrayOfObjects[i] !== undefined ) {
                 arrayOfObjects[i][prop] = obj[prop][i] ;
              } else {
                 var newObj = {} ;
                 newObj[prop] = obj[prop][i] ;
                 arrayOfObjects.push(newObj) ;
              }
         }
    }
}
```